# what other params can I pass to the google hangout uri?

Tags: parameter-passing, google-plus

I recently discovered a parameter to pass to a google hangout uri to make it "on air": [reference](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-plus-discuss/neMXkRRQNFU)

I'm also wondering if I can pass any other parameters.  I know that we have app_id, but I'm more interested to know if there are other parameters, such as being able to set the title or the hangout in advance, e.g.

```
https://plus.google.com/hangouts/_?hso=0&title=EdX%20SaaS%20Pairing
```

Because then I could direct people to https://plus.google.com/u/0/s/%23hangoutsonair%20EdX/hangouts and they could see all the on air hangouts associated with our MOOC.  I did experimentally try passing title=, topic= and name= all to no immediate effect ...

I'd also love to know if there's a way to automatically start the live broadcast, or even better have the hangout be automatically associated with and published to our G+ pair programming community:

https://plus.google.com/communities/100279740984094902927

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Any luck on this one? I was curious if there was a way to set the title programmatically but haven't found anything. There's some evidence that it was possible here: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/google-in-the-enterprise/quick-tip-set-up-a-google-plus-hangout-for-web-conferencing/ (assuming that form had some param it could set for the title) but that UI has been deprecated, so I can't just check to see how it does it.

Comment: The second link is dead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this response from Tim Blasi at Google:

> I'm a developer working on video calling. Unfortunately, you can not currently configure the video call in the way you are describing. However, we've received a lot of feedback that this is a pain point and we're currently working to address it. We'll keep your request in mind as we move forward.

https://plus.google.com/u/0/103524399391704001670/posts/JGtpxgvdD5H

Answer (score 1):

resurrecting an old thread, but for a good reason.

i recently found that its possible to bypass the landing page and pre-select your user account

https://meet.google.com/lookup/my-room-name?authuser=my-email@account.com

just replace `my-room-name` and `my-email@account.com`